# SSAS Data Mining: Testing and Training Data Sets...please explain

Tags: ssas

Can someone explain what happens when you split up the data set for testing and training?

Answer (score 2):

Put simply, the accuracy of your data mining model is evaluated by making predictions based on your training set of which the result is already known in test set.

[More information on the testing and validation of data mining models (MSDN)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174493.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to test the predictive analysis model you built, you need to split your dataset into two sets: training and test datasets. These datasets should be selected at random and should be a good representation of the actual population.

```
Similar data should be used for both the training and test datasets.

Normally the training dataset is significantly larger than the test dataset.

Using the test dataset helps you avoid errors such as overfitting.

The trained model is run against test data to see how well the model will perform.
```

[More Information](http://www.dummies.com/programming/big-data/data-science/how-to-test-the-predictive-analysis-model/)